# How to get Video details from a youtube playlist with Playlist id and video index number

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a video URL like https://www.youtube.com/embed/?list=PLFgquLnL59akA2PflFpeQG9L01VFg90wS&index=8 and I am trying to get video details using playlistId and Index with youtube API v3. But I am confused how to send Index parameter to following request?

```
('GET',
'/youtube/v3/playlistItems',
{
    'maxResults': '25',
    'part': 'snippet,contentDetails',
    'playlistId': 'PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE'
});
```

Comment: You would normally send that request as-is and have it return a list of videos. In the list each video has a `position` property. Refer to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems

Comment: @w0ffen thank you for your comment. In this scenario I want to get details of only one video within the playlist on index 8 :)

Comment: What he's saying is your call will return up to 25 playlistItems so look for position 8.